# Errors while executing a PHP script with crontab

Tags: php, linux, bash, nginx, cron

I'm making a [website](https://github.com/GilDev/La-Guerre-des-631) with PHP5, here's my setup: the website is hosted on a Raspberry Pi running the Raspbian (Debian) OS. I'm using Nginx as a web server with php5-fpm 5.4.39. My website is made using the [Atomik Framework](http://atomikframework.com/) and my script is made with the [ConsoleKit](https://github.com/maximebf/ConsoleKit) plugin (it's a little specific but the problem may be not).

So I have my script, and I run it with `php /path/to/index.php <command>`. It works really great when using it within my shell, but when I try to make cron execute it, it prints me an error saying that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is not defined but that's something I can solve by forcing this variable to some value. After that, just nothing happen and I don't know what to do. I tried everything: different commands, running the command in an outside bash script, with PHP she-bang, none of them works.
Do anyone have an idea of what could cause this? Maybe a different command that cron could run could fix the problem? Is the fact that "no user" (I guess, I'm not a Linux expert) is running the script a problem?

Comment: Do you include any other files, `require_once` or `include_once`?  Because those paths might be problematic when running from cron

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the php code through http like this in your cron:

```
30 11 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://www.example.com/cron.php
```

Comment: Yeah but the script is not available via the web, so that nobody can run it. It's really a script outside of the website, making hidden databases operations.

Answer (score 0):

To debug the problem, you will need to get access to the logs.

```
*/1 * * * * full_path_to_your_php_script.php >> full_path_to_your_log_file.log 2>&1
```

Then check the full_path_to_your_log_file.log file

Comment: Yeah I already tried that. When I force the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` variable to `'GET'`, I get nothing. And when I don't set this variable, I have a bunch of errors from Atomik Framework saying this variable is not set and the script can't proceed (although I don't get these errors while executing the script in-shell, and the variable isn't even set! Really weird…).